# How to use node js child process for installed cli apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a CLI installed app. Whenever I try to use these processes on a child-process, it says that those commands are not found. I've tried importing the source files for configuration and exported them and yet i get the error.

Comment: Could you give an example of the commands you are trying?

Comment: try executing the actual exe file (if on windows) or .bin if on unix variant from node child-process

Comment: Okay, so my installed CLI on unix, has a source configuration file which I source it first 
source my/directory/Source.bash . I've added this line in /.bashrc too. Hence all the commands work on my terminal. 
Eg: fmagain is a command and if i use that on terminal it displays a few results.
Now I try using the exec function on js, and use a bash.sh script having the same command and it doesn't work. Shows up an error message